# Updating an XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am trying to change the PlannedDuration of Activity A04 but I have not been able to see the changes in the XML file. The changes are not updated into the file. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

The XML is too long. The file has information about several activities. I am interested only in the activity with Id A04.

The initial value of the PlannedDuration is 16 and I changed it to 25.

[XML File:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/os9dB.png)

```
package modifyXML;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class ModifyXML{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File xmlfile = new File("C:/Users/dianitaf/Downloads/xml Files/CS_1.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;

        try {
            dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = dBuilder.parse(xmlfile);
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            updateElementValue(document,"Id", "A04");

            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);

            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("xmlfile"));

            transformer.transform(source, result);

            System.out.println("XML file updated successfully");

        } catch (SAXException | ParserConfigurationException | IOException | TransformerException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void updateElementValue(Document document, String textNodeName, String textNodeValue) {

        NodeList Activity = document.getElementsByTagName("Activity");
        Element act = null;

        //loop for each activity
        for(int i=0; i<Activity.getLength();i++){

            Node activityNode = Activity.item(i);
            if(activityNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
            {
                Element activityElement = (Element) activityNode;
                NodeList textNodes = activityElement.getElementsByTagName(textNodeName); 

                if(textNodes.getLength() > 0)
                {

                    if(textNodes.item(0).getTextContent().equalsIgnoreCase(textNodeValue))
                    {

                        System.out.println(textNodes.item(0).getTextContent());
                        System.out.println(activityElement.getElementsByTagName("Name").item(0).getTextContent());

                        act = (Element) Activity.item(i);     
                        Node duration = act.getElementsByTagName("PlannedDuration").item(0).getFirstChild();

                        System.out.println("Initial Duration : " + act.getElementsByTagName("PlannedDuration").item(0).getTextContent()); act.getElementsByTagName("PlannedDuration").item(0).getTextContent();

                        duration.setTextContent("25");

                        System.out.println("Updaded Duration : " + act.getElementsByTagName("PlannedDuration").item(0).getTextContent());
                    }
                }    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to SO. Have you considered to use JAXB ? https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/

Comment: Please format (indent) code for human readability. I wanted to help, but I refuse to look at badly formatted code like this. Edit the question and fix it.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time posting a question. When I copied the code to post the question I was getting an error related to the formatting so I understood that I had to indent everything to avoid that error. That being said, I am a civil engineer trying to learn and understand java, so I will try to do my best editing the code from the question I posted. I apologize in advance for all my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><APIBusinessObjects> 
    <ProjectList>
        <Project ObjectId="4627">
            <Id>CS_1</Id>
            <Name>Case Study No.1 Warehouse Project - CPM</Name>
        </Project>
    </ProjectList> 
    <Project>
        <Activity>
            <Id>A04</Id>
            <Name>Nailers to Purlins</Name>
            <PlannedDuration>16</PlannedDuration>
            <StartDate>2018-12-26Te8:00:00</StartDate>
        </Activity> 
    </Project>
</APIBusinessObjects>
```

**Java:**

```
package modifyXML;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class ModifyXML {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File xmlfile = new File("D:\\delete\\test.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;

        try {
            dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = dBuilder.parse(xmlfile);
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            updateElementValue(document, "Id", "A04");

            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);

            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(xmlfile);

            transformer.transform(source, result);

            System.out.println("XML file updated successfully");

        } catch (SAXException | ParserConfigurationException | IOException | TransformerException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void updateElementValue(Document document, String textNodeName, String textNodeValue) {

        NodeList Activity = document.getElementsByTagName("Activity");
        Element act = null;

        // loop for each activity
        for (int i = 0; i < Activity.getLength(); i++) {

            Node activityNode = Activity.item(i);
            if (activityNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element activityElement = (Element) activityNode;
                NodeList textNodes = activityElement.getElementsByTagName(textNodeName);

                if (textNodes.getLength() > 0) {

                    if (textNodes.item(0).getTextContent().equalsIgnoreCase(textNodeValue)) {

                        System.out.println(textNodes.item(0).getTextContent());
                        System.out.println(activityElement.getElementsByTagName("Name").item(0).getTextContent());

                        act = (Element) Activity.item(i);
                        Node duration = act.getElementsByTagName("PlannedDuration").item(0).getFirstChild();

                        System.out.println("Initial Duration : "
                                + act.getElementsByTagName("PlannedDuration").item(0).getTextContent());
                        act.getElementsByTagName("PlannedDuration").item(0).getTextContent();

                        duration.setTextContent("25");

                        System.out.println("Updaded Duration : "
                                + act.getElementsByTagName("PlannedDuration").item(0).getTextContent());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You were almost there. The xml you posted had a minor typo (ProjectList tag was not ended). In code I have replaced << StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("xmlfile"));>> with <<StreamResult result = new StreamResult(xmlfile); >>. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thank you! It removed the quotation marks but it says that the constructor File is undefined.

Comment: May be some small thing being missed. I think you have removed the quotation only. It will not work. As your goal is to update the same xml file that you have used for reading, you don't need to create new file instance, use the existing one instead. So, it is not <<new StreamResult(new File(xmlfile));>>, it is <<new StreamResult(xmlfile);>> instead.Try the code that I shared in my answer above. I have tested it on JDK 7.